# How to create a function that incrementally reduces opacity of 2 lines every time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, svg, button, opacity

I am new to coding and I am trying to create a function that incrementally reduces the opacity of 2 lines every time a button is clicked (similar to a staircase design). This is the function that I have so far:

```
this.options.events['click button'] = function() {
  document.querySelector('#color_bottom').style.opacity = 0.7
  document.querySelector('#color_right').style.opacity = 0.7
};
```

The above function changes the opacity of two lines (#color_right) and (#color_bottom) from 1 to 0.7. But I need help coming up with a function that will incrementally reduce the opacity say by 0.1 for every time the button is clicked.

All your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `-=` as in `document.querySelector('#color_bottom').style.opacity -= 0.1`

Comment: @mplungjan hi that does not work

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56837245/edit) then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the references to both lines in an array, set the default opacity value and then decrease the opacity on every button click:

```js
const step = 0.1

const lines = ['color_bottom', 'color_right']
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id))
    .map(el => {
        el.style.opacity = 1
        return el
    });

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    lines.forEach(line => {
        line.style.opacity -= step
    })
});
```

```html
<p id="color_bottom">Line 1</p>
<p id="color_right">Line 2</p>
<button>Reduce Opacity</button>
```

Comment: Hi @r1111 I have updated the answer, it reduces the opacity now as requested

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain one global variable with the initial value `1`. On clicking the button each time decrease that variable by `0.1`.

**Demo:**

```js
let start = 1;
function increaseOpacity() {
  start -= 0.1;
  document.querySelector('#color_bottom').style.opacity = start;
  document.querySelector('#color_right').style.opacity = start;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="increaseOpacity()">Decrease</button>
<div id="color_bottom">color_bottom</div>
<div id="color_right">color_right</div>
```

Comment: would the div{ opacity } still be inside the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small example. You can change the logic as you need.

```
const sub = 0.1;
var main = 1;
this.options.events['click button'] = function() {
    if (main > 0) {
        document.querySelector('#color_bottom').style.opacity = main - sub;
        document.querySelector('#color_right').style.opacity = main - sub;
    } else {
        main = 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the value of the `stroke-opacity` attribute of the lines:

```js
let lines = document.querySelectorAll("line");
let so = 1;//the initial stroke opacity is set to 1
theButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(so > 0){so -=.1;// if the stroke opacity is greater than 1 decrease it
  lines.forEach(l=>{// reset the stroke-opacity attribute of the lines
    l.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-opacity",so)
  })
  }
})
```

```css
line{stroke:black}
svg{border:1px solid; stroke-width:5; width:90vh;}
```

```html
<p><button id="theButton">theButton</button></p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <line x1="10" y1="90" x2="85" y2="90" stroke-opacity="1" />
  <line y1="10" x1="90" y2="85" x2="90" stroke-opacity="1" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: would I put the line{stroke:black} inside the script tag?

Comment: do you need to set the color in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.example');
let opacity = 1;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 opacity -= 0.2;
 this.style.opacity = opacity;
});
```

```css
.example {
    background-color:blue;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="example">Button</button>
```